# Is there a way to stop nth (n) child at number u want?

Tags: css, sass

I am typing this code and I need to stop it at 29 while my all childs are like 100-150:

```
&:nth-child(1n+1)
```

Is there any trick to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this function notation. Cheers

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: gray 1px dotted;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f00;
  margin: .25rem;
}

div:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
}

div:nth-child(-n+29) {
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```